# Node.js JSON.parse "Unexpected token {"

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a script that uses `JSON.parse(datastring);` to parse a stringified JSON.

datastrings look like this:

```
{"_id":"8b8fdd243f734b27829c92e4099f70ec.d","date":1439418654920,"player":"player1","action":"capture"}
{"_id":"a3b7d70d8a074f9ba8b13368ee947f1e.d","date":1439418074476,"player":"player1","action":"capture"}
```

First one works just fine, but with the second one I get a weird error, that I can't find a way to solve.

```
undefined:2
{"_id":"a3b7d70d8a074f9ba8b13368ee947f1e.d","date": 1439418074476,"player":"pla
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/lib/engine.js:12:18)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:765:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:427:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:423:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:166:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:128:10)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:529:21)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: that's not a valid JSON string

Comment: @JaromandaX it's generated in the same way as "valid" one before

Comment: oh, sorry, I misread the question, I thought that the two lines was the **whole** string that gave you errors

Comment: JSON parsers usually expect only a single, complete value. You currently have 2 independent Objects side-by-side with nothing truly connecting them. Best guess is that you need to wrap them in an Array, separating them with a comma.

Comment: If you are parsing them together it will not work as it is not valid json.

This should work for you though.
[{"_id":"8b8fdd243f734b27829c92e4099f70ec.d","date":1439418654920,"player":"player1","action":"capture"},
{"_id":"a3b7d70d8a074f9ba8b13368ee947f1e.d","date":1439418074476,"player":"player1","action":"capture"}]

Comment: it's great seeing people read the comments - according to @fivepointseven those two strings are independently parsed

Comment: need to see some code around the problem - I think you may be concatenating the first line to the second line which is why you'd have the problem, as, each line stand alone is perfectly valid JSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JSON.parse` expects to be passed a string containing a JSON text, not a string containing *multiple* JSON texts.

Either parse each line (assuming you can trust that line breaks will only be between the JSON texts in your input) separately…

```
var json_texts = datastring.split("\n");
```

… or express the data in an array to start with.

```
[
    {"_id":"8b8fdd243f734b27829c92e4099f70ec.d","date":1439418654920,"player":"player1","action":"capture"},
    {"_id":"a3b7d70d8a074f9ba8b13368ee947f1e.d","date":1439418074476,"player":"player1","action":"capture"}
]
```

Comment: `datastrings look like this:` (note the plural) - `First one works just fine, but with the second one I get a weird error` - I think the two lines are parsed individually (perhaps retrieved separately?)

Comment: @JaromandaX — The error message disagrees. There is no way it would complain about the `{` that is the *first* character of the string being an unexpected token.

Comment: I started posting exactly the same solution, so I agree with you, but I'm  going by his response to my comment `it's generated in the same way as "valid" one before` and re-reading the question with that in mind

Comment: Parse is executed on event where datastring is passed. It's the only string processed at a time.

Comment: @fivepointseven — I suspect you'll find that each time it is passed either (a) you get a chunk of data that broken up based on either bytes or time and not by line and/or (b) You get all the data received so far and not just the most recent chunk. The simple way to confirm that would be to log the value of `datastring` before you try parsing it as JSON.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I tried adding `console.log('every: ' + datastring)' and sometimes I indeed get 2-3-4 of them in one string. I have to figure out where is this happening in my code, but your solution works. Thanks!

Comment: @fivepointseven That's how node streams work, they are just streams of bytes, they are not grouped by messages or packets or anything. If you want them to do, you'll need to do that explicitly.